# How much does a driver weigh?

Tags: car, weight

I was amused when I saw one of the statistics for my VW Passat B5.5 car, which stated as follows:

> Kerb weight with driver - 1425kg

I know this is a very weird question and I hope its not too inappropriate to ask here on a "Maintenance & Repair" site.

***How much does VW's driver weigh?***

In other words, what is the *actual* kerb weight of the car?

Comment: Simply brilliant!  Laughing violently.

Comment: Laden or Unladen? African, or European?

Comment: European - I *think* the kerb weight refers to an unlaiden car.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling - 24 miles per hour - the internet has worked out out!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at [this page](http://www.ultimatespecs.com/car-specs/Volkswagen/2964/Volkswagen-Passat-B55-19-TDI-130-6sp.html), it shows the curb weight of a **Volkswagen Passat B5.5 1.9 TDI 130 6sp** to be 1342 kg. Subtracting this from your number, it comes up with 83 kg for your driver weight, or about 183 lbs for us 'Mericans ;-) This should be fairly close as long as it is the same spec as yours. It should be fairly close, though. I'd imagine there are some differences in curb weight between the automatic and standard versions, but it's not going to be that great of a difference. Besides, 83 kg seems like a fairly usable *average* for driver weight ... but that's getting into opinion realm.

Comment: In the US, most airlines assume a passenger weight of 180 pounds in summer and 185 pounds in winter. So 183 pounds is pretty consistent with that,

Comment: @timbo - Thanks for the confirmation on that ... good to know :D

Comment: Mines a Passat S 2.0L non turbo 5sp, but I don't imagine that would effect the weight much on average. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm still laughing over this question.  Never seen documentation like that. Can't believe you actually found the answer to this.  lol

Comment: So in about a week I'll have to accept the above as the weight of the driver... you'd think it would depend on what I had for breakfast! Apparently not... :)